# How does Rails decide whether to load "Controller.css" or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I created a new Rails app and when I am in some view of a controller called Welcome, if I check the source code I see that the `welcome.css` is being added, even though I don't specify that in the layout or explicitly anywhere in my code.

However, in another Rails app when I am in a controller, let's call it welcome, whenever I am in the view, I don't see the welcome.css being loaded.

How does Rails decide whether yes or not require the css for a specific controller? From the Rails guides it seemed to me that you have to specificly add the `stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]` in order to load the specific css, but this is not the case in my first application, where I don't set that anywhere.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? (it matters because it's either the asset-pipeline in 3.1+, or loading :all)

Comment: I am using Rails 3.1.3 in the one that doesn't load them, and Rails 3.2.2 in the one that automatically loads the controller.css

Comment: hi Smith, did i misunderstand your question? as you didn't accept my answer, I am wondering whether I was misunderstanding your question. if so, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

By default in rails 3.2, rails adds a stylesheet_link_tag in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

and requires all your stylesheets in the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

that's the reason why your rails 3.2.2 app adds all your stylesheets automatically. if you don't want to load all your stylesheets, just edit these two files.